# Getting CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct error

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, class

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to learn (I've been asking a few questions lately on it - my only programming knowledge is in Python, PHP and Javascript). Anyway, I found some examples on the web for how to generate a picklist in C#, and I'm trying to use/modify them to fit my existing code. The results are coming up with an expected class error - but I'm creating a class! Here's my code:

```
private void PeerReview()
{

            MySqlConnection connection;
            string connStringName = "server=localhost;database=hourtracking;uid=username;password=password";
            connection = new MySqlConnection(connStringName);

            cmd.CommandText = "select name from peer_review_info where active_status=1";
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    ListItem item = new ListItem();
                    item.Text = sdr["peerrevid"].ToString();
                    item.Value = sdr["peerrevid"].ToString();
                    item.Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["IsSelected"]);
                    chkPeerRev.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
           connection.Close();
        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        this.PeerReview();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, or am I just using a method of a class that does not exist?

Comment: Where do you get this error? (Where are the coloured squiggles?)

Comment: Can you show the whole code, including class?

Answer (score 2):

You have too many closing braces. Should be:

```
private void PeerReview()
{    
    MySqlConnection connection;
    string connStringName =
        "server=localhost;database=hourtracking;uid=username;password=password";
    connection = new MySqlConnection(connStringName);

    cmd.CommandText = "select name from peer_review_info where active_status=1";
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            ListItem item = new ListItem();
            item.Text = sdr["peerrevid"].ToString();
            item.Value = sdr["peerrevid"].ToString();
            item.Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["IsSelected"]);
            chkPeerRev.Items.Add(item);
        }
   }
   connection.Close();
}
```

Well, actually it needs more changes than that; the `connection` needs a `using`, and it is **very** unclear where `cmd` is defined, but that also needs a `using` and should not be shared (it should be scoped to this method). I would rewrite as:

```
private void PeerReview()
{    
    string connStringName = SomethingExternal.GetConnectionString();

    using(var connection = new MySqlConnection(connStringName))
    using(var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText =
            "select name from peer_review_info where active_status=1";
        connection.Open();
        using (var sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                ListItem item = new ListItem();
                item.Text = sdr["peerrevid"].ToString();
                item.Value = sdr["peerrevid"].ToString();
                item.Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["IsSelected"]);
                chkPeerRev.Items.Add(item);
            }
       }
   }
}
```